# python how to assign 2 values with comma separate for single key in configuration file

Tags: python-3.x, list, anaconda

I have output like this :

```
x~y
x~z
y~x
y~z
```

But I want output like:

```
x~y,z
y~x,z
```

This is My Python Code:

```
allfields=['x','y','z'];

requiredfields=['x','y']

for rf in requiredfields:  
    for af in allfields:
        if rf not in af:
            txt=(rf+" ~ "+af)
            print(txt)
```

Comment: `"\n".join(map(lambda rf: rf + "~" + ",".join(filter(lambda af: af not in rf, allfields)), requiredfields))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `join` the values of `allfields` before printing them:

```
for rf in requiredfields:
    txt = rf + "~" + ",".join(a for a in allfields if a not in rf)
    print(txt)
```

Of course, you could also using `join` to collapse the outer loop:

```
print("\n".join(rf + "~" + ",".join(a for a in allfields if a not in rf) \
for rf in requiredfields))
```